# My env file does not seem to working.

Tags: node.js

This is my keys.js file and the node after running it. And this is my env file. Is there something wrong with this that is giving me that "undefined" in node?

[image] [image]

Comment: Did you source the env file?

Comment: @ManasJayanth I ran the npm install dotenv, but shouldn’t that automatically store what’s in the env?

Answer (score 0):

`dotenv` needs to be invoked as early as possible in your application.

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

If you name your file containing enviromental variables differently or place it in a different locations, specify it as follows

```
require('dotenv').config({path: '/full/custom/path/to/your/env/vars'})
```